# Titanium Studio Application does not run in Android emulator and device

Tags: javascript, html, performance, titanium-mobile

1. Hi I am new to titanium framework.I installed the latest titanium 3.x framework. When I execute the application I got the following errors.Please correct me.Thank you.

   `[ERROR] Error(s) compiling generated Java code
       [ERROR] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_16). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.`  Thank you.

   ```
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Flow
       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.<init>(JavaCompiler.java:315)
       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.instance(JavaCompiler.java:72)
       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:340)
       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
       at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
       at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:69)
       at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.main(Main.java:54)
   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Flow
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
       ... 7 more
   Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: ZIP_Read: error reading zip file
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1200(ZipFile.java:29)
       at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:447)
       at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:97)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:256)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
       ... 13 more
   [ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
   [ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 20s 892ms`
   ```

Comment: Have you installed java in your system, if yes what is the java version?

Comment: Thank You,i am using JDK 1.6.0

Comment: If your system is 64 bit, try to install 32 bit java and 64 bit java in your system